# HighCharts : Exporting jpeg with background in styled mode

Tags: highcharts, export, styled-components

I am using styled mode for rendering highcharts and have set
.highcharts-background
{ fill: transparent}

in scss, which works fine for displaying charts on screen, but when I try to export to jpeg, using exporting plugin, it renders it black, since I understand that jpeg don't support transparent, so it picks black.

The solution was to set the background color in exporting object:

```
exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#9E9E9E'
        }
    }
}
```

Since I am using styled mode, how do I do the same ?  Is there some colorIndex etc way, that I can use ?

Comment: Could you provide a simple example (e.g. in JSFiddle) which recreates described behavior?

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to accomplish if you already can have different background styles for the browser display and the downloadable version. What am I missing?

Comment: @alotropico, I do not know how to set backgroundColor for download mechanism in "Styled mode", where you define the styles using css.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set the style explicitly for exporting, which is different from the style used for the main charts by creating a custom class in scss, and setting that custom class to be used by the exporting object.

so in scss :

```
.exporting_chart_class .highcharts-background { fill: white; }
```

and set the above class to exporting configuration in your js code

```
exporting: {
   chartOptions: {
      chart: {
         className: 'exporting_chart_class'
      }
   }
}
```